# I guess this way of saying is old fashioned, wrong?

Tags: expressions

This is a line of one of the Sherlock Holmes' stories and I guess the bold part would be old fashioned. May I check with you, please?

> I could not help laughing at the ease with which he explained his process of deduction. "When I hear you give your reasons," I remarked, "**the thing always appears to me to be so ridiculously simple** that I could easily do it myself, though at each successive instance of your reasoning I am baffled until you explain your process. And yet I believe that my eyes are as good as yours."

**Today**, it would be, I guess,

> **the thing always appears me so ridiculously simple**

Am I wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Not quite. *Appear* never takes an indirect object; the 'recipient' of the appearance is always expressed with a *to* preposition phrase, as in Doyle's original. And the 'long form' with *to be* is by no means outdated; indeed, the construction without *to be* is apt to seem rather formal today. A slightly more colloquial structure might put the recipient after the predicative complement: *The thing appears so ridiculously simple to me...*

Comment: It certainly sounds British, but not necessarily old-fashioned.

Comment: You could omit the “to be” if you wanted, but you must include the “to” after “appears”: ***the thing always appears*** **to** ***me so ridiculously simple***